# Probability of a set of random integers containing number in specific range

Tags: probability

Given a finite set $S$ of $n$ uniformly distributed random nonnegative integers smaller than $k$ and two integers $0 \leq a, b \leq k$, what is the probability that there is an $x\in S, a \leq x < b$?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you do it if $n=1$?  If the answer to that is $p$, then for $n=2$ (or more) just compute $1-(1-p)^n$.

Comment: @lulu Wouldn't that ignore the fact that there are $n$ different numbers?

Comment: No.  The event  "at least one element of $S$ lies in the subinterval" is the complement of "all elements of $S$ lie outside the subinterval".

Comment: @lulu Your solution is based on the assumption that the $n$ integers are independently distributed, which is not the case since they must all be distinct for $S$ to contain $n$ elements. I think what D0r1an means is that $S$ is uniformly distributed among all $n$-element sets of nonnegative integers smaller than $k$.

Comment: @McFry Well, that's a possible (but I'd say unusual) reading.  I took the problem to mean "we choose $n$ integers uniformly at random from $\{0,\cdots , k\}$".  I assumed the selection was independent. If, to the contrary, the OP means to say "we choose $n$ cards without replacement from a collection of $k$ cards" that is very different and should be spelled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\binom{X}{n}$ denote the set of all $n$-element subsets of a set $X$. We have $|\binom{X}{n}| = \binom{|X|}{n}$.

If I understand the problem correctly, $S$ is supposed to be a random $n$-element subset of the $k$-element set $A :=\{0, \ldots, k-1\}$, where all such $n$-element subsets are equally likely. What this means is that $S$ is a uniformly distributed random element of $\binom{A}{n}$.

The subsets in $\binom{A}{n}$ that do not contain any number in $\{a, \ldots, b-1\}$ must be $n$-element subsets of the set $B := \{0, \ldots, a-1, b, \ldots, k-1\}$, the set of which is $\binom{B}{n} \subset \binom{A}{n}$.

The probability we are looking for is now the probability that a random element $S$ of $\binom{A}{n}$ contains an element of $A \smallsetminus B$, which is the case iff it is not in $\binom{B}{n}$. Therefore this probability is

$$\frac{|\binom{A}{n} \smallsetminus \binom{B}{n}|}{|\binom{A}{n}|} = \frac{|\binom{A}{n}| - |\binom{B}{n}|}{|\binom{A}{n}|} = 1 - \frac{|\binom{B}{n}|}{|\binom{A}{n}|} = 1 - \frac{\binom{|B|}{n}}{\binom{|A|}{n}} = 1 - \frac{\binom{k-b+a}{n}}{\binom{k}{n}}.$$

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be what I'm looking for.